# Confused on how AWK processes commands

Tags: bash, csv, awk

So for this question I am going to give two sample code blocks with one slight difference. Sample 1 giving correct results and sample 2 giving incorrect.
Correct results here means that it should be able to read in what fields it should read from a csv file and print the count of the strings present in those fields only. Example shown below after sample code.
Note the program is made to skip header lines in CSV files.

SAMPLE 1:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FIELDS_LIST = ARGV[1];
    delete ARGV[1];
    FS = ", *"

    num = split(FIELDS_LIST,arr,",")
    for(i in arr)
        fields[arr[i]]
}

{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        if(FNR != 1)
          if(i in fields)
            data[++data_index] = $i
    }

}

END {
    produce_numbers(data)

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"

    for(i in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", i, freq[i]
}

function produce_numbers(sortedarray)
{
    n = asort(sortedarray)

    for(i = 1 ; i <= n; i++)
    {
        freq[sortedarray[i]]++
    }
    return
}
```

SAMPLE 2:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FIELDS_LIST = ARGV[1];
    delete ARGV[1];
    FS = ", *"

    num = split(FIELDS_LIST,arr,",")
    for(i in arr)
        fields[arr[i]]
}

{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        if(FNR != 1)
          if(i in arr)                 #This is the only line changed, fields was changed to arr
            data[++data_index] = $i
    }

}

END {
    produce_numbers(data)

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"

    for(i in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", i, freq[i]
}

function produce_numbers(sortedarray)
{
    n = asort(sortedarray)

    for(i = 1 ; i <= n; i++)
    {
        freq[sortedarray[i]]++
    }
    return
}
```

The code is to be called with something like `./example-awk.awk 2,3 simple.csv` with simple.csv containing

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
A,V,A,C
B,C,V,D
E,W,C,A
```

and the result should be

```
V    2
C    2
A    1
W    1
```

Sample 1 provides the correct result, sample 2 however provides

```
A    1
B    1
C    1
E    1
W    1
V    1
```

Showing that it is only reading from fields 1 and 2, not 2 and 3 as it was specified to from the command line arguments.
I want to know *why* making a second array in begin and then using that instead of the original arr solves the problem.

Comment: Why not print the i's that are in field and not in arr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (i in arr)
```

tests if `i` is a key in the `arr` array. But the field numbers you want are the values in the array, not the indexes.

Instead of looping over all the fields and testing them, you can loop over `arr` and just fetch those fields.

Also, you should test for `FNR != 1` before executing any of the code for the line, to skip the header, rather than every time through the loop.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FIELDS_LIST = ARGV[1];
    delete ARGV[1];
    FS = ", *"

    num = split(FIELDS_LIST,arr,",")
    for(i in arr)
        fields[arr[i]]
}

FNR != 1 {
    for (i in fields)
        data[++data_index] = $i
}

END {
    produce_numbers(data)

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"

    for(i in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", i, freq[i]
}

function produce_numbers(sortedarray)
{
    n = asort(sortedarray)

    for(i = 1 ; i <= n; i++)
    {
        freq[sortedarray[i]]++
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain what exactly a key is? I am not familiar with AWK enough to fully understand.

Comment: When you assign an array element, `fields[x] = y`, `x` is the key and `y` is the value.

Comment: It's like the array index in a traditional array.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for your time!